# pry で up や down が使えない場合がある

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pry

たまに rails のプロジェクトで、 pry (より正確には `binding.pry` から起動する pry) において、 up や down が使えない場合があります。

#### 質問

- pry において up や down を実行するために必要な設定 (もしくは gem?) などはあるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自分はずっと、 `pry-byebug` を利用していたのですが、これと、 `pry-stack_explorer` は非互換だそうです。

https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug#alternatives

gem ファイルの依存関係に、 `pry-byebug` と `pry-stack_explorer` の両方をいれていると、どうやら、 up/down の挙動がおかしくなる模様です。 `pry-stack_explorer` を削除した結果、動作は安定するようになりました。

Answer (score 2):

`pry-stack_explorer`ですね。
https://github.com/pry/pry-stack_explorer